# Workbench : UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1813006708-15724 (-1389071712)

Tags: workbench

I am trying to insert a csv of Account Team members using Workbench and I keep receiving this error without any info.

I have the Account ID, User ID, Member Role, Account Access, Opportunity Access, Contact Access included in the csv file.

Comment: There's very little that non-Salesforce employees can do with those error Ids (unless someone happens to have run into the same error). That error id is what you'd give to Salesforce's official customer support (most of us regular contributors are professionals who work in the Salesforce ecosystem, and not employees of Salesforce). Have you tried another tool like the Salesforce-provided Data Loader or Dataloader.io?

Comment: Based on the GACK ID, I see the details in our internal logs as "Length of actual parameter value exceeds declared length of pljava call argument (19 vs 15)" Can you make sure all Ids are 15 characters long and try the insertion again?Thanks

Comment: @Swetha in the interest of helping the wider community, is there anything in that ID specific to that error, or is it specific to this particular invocation?

Comment: Based on the stack trace(here -1389071712) of [GACKID](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tag/gack) the details of the error could be determined. Multiple users encountering the same stacktraceID will face the same error.

Comment: This question has been flagged by automation as spam, which appears to have resulted in a number of automated downvotes that I do not believe are warranted here.